# PHP and JSON - Decoded Array Issue?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get some info out of a decoded JSon string into an array.

I've this code:

```
$json_d='{ // This is just an example, I normally get this from a request...
             "iklive.com":{"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"domcno"}
}';

$json_a=json_decode($json_d,true);
$full_domain = $domain.$tlds; // $domain = 'iklive' ; $tlds = '.com'

echo $json_a[$full_domain][status];
```

The problem is, I need to get the value for "status" of "iklive.com" but when I do `echo $json_a[$full_domain][status];` it does not work, but if I do it manually like `echo $json_a['iklive.com'][status];` (with the quotes there) it works.

I've tried to add the quotes to the variable but without success, how can I do this?

Thanks Everyone!

---

Thanks to Pekka and jeromegamez I noticed a error in the HTML part of this "problem", the `$tlds` variable was "com" instead of ".com" -- Sorry by wasting your time with this. I do feel bad now.

Anyway, thanks to jeromegamez and Marc B I discovered that unless `status` was a constant I need to quote it ;) You can check jeromegamez answer to a detailed explanation of the problem and proper debug.

Sorry.

Comment: And the value of `$full_domain` is?

Comment: Are you sure that `$full_domain='iklive.com'`?

Comment: You are 100% positive `$full_domain` has that value? Then there shouldn't be a problem. Are you keeping in mind that array indexes are case sensitive?

Comment: Actually, neither should work, because `status` hasn't been quoted. Unless you've got a `status` constant define()'d, a PHP install in strict mode should gripe about both versions.

Comment: can you make a var_dump on $full_domain?

Comment: @comfreek: and issue a warning.

Comment: @MarcB On my installation it's a E_NOTICE.

Comment: What do you get exactly when you echo $full_domain ?? And also make sure there's no spaces in there.

Comment: Thanks everyone, but now I feel so bad and stupid by wasting people time with this. The problem is that I was getting the `$tlds` from a form posted over. And it was not including the `.` after I made some changes :S You can kill me now. Sorry :(

Comment: @Marc B - I've placed it quoted now thanks! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<?php
$json_d='{ "iklive.com":{"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"domcno"} }';
$json_a = json_decode($json_d, true);

if (!is_array($json_a)) {
    echo "\$json_d is not a valid JSON array\n";
}

$domain = "iklive";
$tld = ".com";
$full_domain = $domain . $tld;

if (!isset($json_a[$full_domain])) {
    echo "{$full_domain} is not set in \$json_a\n";
} else {
    echo $json_a[$full_domain]['status']."\n";
}
```

What I did:

- Changed `json_a[$full_domain][status]` to `json_a[$full_domain]['status']` - the missing quotes around `status` don't break your script, but raise a `Notice: Use of undefined constant status - assumed 'status'`
- Added a check if the decoded JSON is actually an array
- Added a check whether the key `$full_domain` is set in `$json_a`

Comment: You're the best! I discovered by problem was a stupid mistake done in the HTML file that posts the $domain and $tld variables. Sorry by wasting your time guys. Anyway, I noticed also I was not using `['status']` quoted! Thanks! ;)

Comment: Helped me for Drupal Json Decode as well where it was giving a bunch of similar error messages